# Why the system freezed (not sending /recving messages)?

Tags: c++, linux

I have 2 C++ application which run on Linux.
One application has 2 connections: ETH and serial (232)
The second application has one connection (ETH connection, which connect to the first application).

Sometimes (very rare) it seems that the eth/serial connection are being freeze for several seconds.
In those seconds, I can see my application logs (The applications are not freeze) but no messages are being received. 
(The 2 applications sending and receiving messages at ~10HZ rate)

Is there a way to check the linux log which tell me when and why there was a freeze on the system connections ?

Thanks

Comment: You can use `tcpdump` to monitor what's happening on the network connection, I don't know if there's anything similar for serial lines. unix.stackexchange.com would be a better place to ask.

Comment: I cant use tcpdump becuse the freeze if for 3-5 seconds, and is very rare.

Comment: There are no logs of these kinds of things. Unless it's a hardware problem, that might get mentioned in `dmesg`.

Comment: Ca you run the application under `strace`?